# Is there something that causes quick sort algorithms to segfault when done on a vector size divisible by 7?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have what I believe to be a quicksort algorithm that produces a segfault about halfway though when performed on a vector thats size is divisible by 7. It appears to work normally on other sizes and produces correct results. Is this a normal occurrence or is it just an error that I am over looking.

```
    /******************************************************************************
 * Function to do the quicksort by recursive call to the substep.
**/
void RecordArray::quicksort()
{
  comparisonsQuick = 0;
  swapsQuick = 0;
  quicksortSubstep(0, recs.size(), comparisonsQuick, swapsQuick);
}

/******************************************************************************
 * Function to do the quicksort.
**/
void RecordArray::quicksortSubstep(int leftBound, int rightBound,
                                   LONG& localComparisons, LONG& localSwaps)
{
  int i = leftBound;
  int j = rightBound;
  OneRecord temp;
  int pivotPoint = (leftBound + rightBound) / 2;
  cout << pivotPoint << endl;
  OneRecord pivot = recs[pivotPoint];;
  while(i <= j)
  {
    while(recs[i] < pivot)
    {
      i++;
      localComparisons++;
    }
    while(recs[j] > pivot)
    {
      j--;
      localComparisons++;
    }
    if(i <= j)
    {
      localComparisons++;
      localSwaps++;
      //cout << localSwaps << " = swaps" << endl;
      temp = recs[i];
      recs[i] = recs[j];
      recs[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
    //cout << localComparisons << " = comparisons" << endl;
  }
  if(leftBound < j)
  {
    //cout << leftBound << " , " << j << endl;
    //cout << "The top one" << endl;
    quicksortSubstep(leftBound, j, localComparisons, localSwaps);
  }
  if(i < rightBound)
  { 
    //cout << i << " , " << rightBound << endl;
    //cout << "The bottom one" << endl;
    quicksortSubstep(i, rightBound, localComparisons, localSwaps);
  }
}
```

The algorithm sorts a Vector of records which is simply another vector that contains 4 integers. I have overloaded the operators in the Record class and the segfault occurs inside of the overloaded less than class when it first compares the two records inside of the vector. The vector size that is being sorted during the segfault is 511, which is divisible by 7. And the two values of "recs" that are being compared in the while loop are 182 and 225 respectively. Both being within 0 and 510 I'm not sure how one of them could be null. the "recs[i]" (recs[182]) is what causes the segfault when it is looked at in the overloaded lessThan class.

Sorry if this was too long, just wanted to try and present as much information as I could deem useful. The lessThan class below is called by the actual overload class, just to make it slightly neater. This was tried on other vectors and everything seems to work fine unless the size is divisible by 7. And all of the cout statements are just for debugging purposes.

```
/******************************************************************************
 * Function 'lessThan' to return a boolean "recA < recB"
 *
 * Parameter:
 *   that - the 'OneRecord' to compare against.
**/
bool OneRecord::lessThan(const OneRecord& that) const
{
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < theValues.size(); i++)
  {
    if(this->theValues[i] < that.getValues()[i])
    {
      //cout << "if " << this->theValues[i] << " is less than " << that.getValues()[i] << " return true;" << endl;
      return true;
    }

    if(this->theValues[i] > that.getValues()[i])
    {
      //cout << "if " << this->theValues[i] << " is less than " << that.getValues()[i] << " return false;" << endl;
      break;
    }
    if(this->theValues[i] == that.getValues()[i] && i == (theValues.size())-1)
    {
      //cout << "got to the last one";
      //cout << "if " << this->theValues[i] << " is less than " << that.getValues()[i] << " return false;" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Whenever you find yourself thinking the ____ (OS, API, runtime function, std member, etc) might have a blatantly obvious bug, stop and consider that at best it's merely a hint as to what's wrong with _your_ code.

Comment: @CareyGregory Oh I'm sure it's something that I've done wrong, I simply worded the question the way I did to see if it was a common misuse/error that is made.

Comment: Exactly where in your program (what line) does it crash on?

Comment: @selbie it crashes at the first if statement in the lessThan class

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about the state of *this at that line?

Comment: @selbie it says that its an invalid read of size 4 and that Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd. So its reading in what is supposed to be an integer but is set to null

Comment: The bug may be somewhere outside of the code you presented. Can you provide a minimal working example? Try to reduce it to a code that would be as short as possible. Chances are that when you try to reduce it, the bug will fix itself, giving you a hint where to look for it. SO is not a code review site.

Comment: `while(i <= j)` Half-open intervals. Do you speak them?

Comment: @n.m. sorry i'm not sure what you mean. I found the algorithm itself online and manipulated it to work for my situation.

Comment: If you don't know what "half open interval" means, google it and read everything you can. It is a basic notion you need if you want to work with arrays in C or C++. Basically it means that if you say something like `while (index <= array_size)` you are probably doing it wrong. You either do (almost always) `< array_size` or (rarely) `<= last_index`. Generalized, in a pair of indices representing a range the second one should (almost always) point to *one past the last element*.

Comment: You call `quicksortSubstep(0, recs.size(), ...` and the first and the second parameters become `i` and `j`. Wrong! Adjust all your code to either half-open `[start, end)` intervals and do `index < end`, or to closed `[first, last]` intervals and do `index <= last`. Remember that end=last+1. The answer says basically the same but without all the theory ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
while(recs[j] > pivot)
```

`j` starts with the value `rightBound`. `rightBound` in the first call is `recs.size()`.

So you have the equivalent of accessing `recs[recs.size()]` which is outside the array boundaries of `recs` and is undefined behaviour.

I think you could pass in `recs.size()-1` in the first call, but I haven't looked at all of your code.

Comment: That makes sense to me but whenever I do that it sends my program in an infinite loop and nothing works. I'm not sure how it is currently sorting all of the other vectors.

Comment: I take back what I said. It works now. I have no idea what I did besides doing what you suggested. Maybe I just failed to compile. Thanks for helping me see the logic.